# Discord Bot Error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, discord

I'm fairly new to code so I'm not exactly sure what I did wrong here.
I'm currently trying to create a discord bot with an 8-ball command. The command is triggered when someone types $eight-ball and will respond with

- "Yes- definitely"
- "As I see it, yes."
- "Yes"
- "Signs point to yes"
- "Can't be certain"
- "..."
- "It's better not tell you now"
- "My reply is no."
- "My sources say no"
- "Outlook not so good."

If anyone who knows how to code something like that in python, please help.

```
import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands


client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command()
async def test(context):
    pass

bot.add_command = ('eight_ball')

@bot.command(name='eight_ball',
            description="Answers a yes/no question.",
            brief="Answers from the beyond.",
            aliases=['eight_ball', 'eightball', '8-ball'],
            pass_context=True)

async def eight_ball(context):
    possible_responses = [

        'Yes- definitely',
        'As I see it, yes.',
        'Yes',
        'Signs point to yes.',
        'Can\'t be certain.',
        '...',
        'It\'s better not tell you now.',
        'My reply is no.'
        'My sources say no.'
        'Outlook not so good'


    ]
    await context.channel.send(random.choice(possible_responses) + ", " + context.message.author.mention)

client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
---------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
    async def eight_ball(context):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1263, in decorator
    self.add_command(result)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove `'eight_ball'` from `aliases` in the `@bot.command` decorator?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the line `bot.add_command = ('eight_ball')`, this is overriding a function that is called when adding a command to the bot with a non-function.

Also, you have a duplicate alias `eight_ball` in your alias list (duplicate of the name) which will result in a `CommandRegistrationError`.